# Grails, Nimble and Blogito

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I tried to run the sample application of Nimble 0.2 (blogito) downloaded [here](http://github.com/intient/blogito) but unfortunately I got stuck with 2 major issues:

When running `grails run-app`, I got 2 times out of 3 the following error :

```
2009-10-24 14:38:15,198 [main] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowExecutionSnapshotFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowRegistry' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowBuilderServices' while setting bean property 'flowBuilderServices'...
```

I have also a similar issue on my project running Nimble 0.3-SNAPSHOT

But sometimes, it works (really... I don't know why... it's magical...) So I can use the blogito app until I need to create a local account and I got the following exception:

```
2009-10-24 14:30:31,846 [4974549@qtp0-4] ERROR view.GroovyPageView  - Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <n:recaptcharequired>: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:enabled for class: com.megatome.grails.RecaptchaService
```

So is there anyone here who has ever solved these issues? Do you have any idea about the problems? Do I need to open an issue on Nimble project?

Thx,

Fabien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some have encountered the same issue and if you are interested into the solution, I got the answer in another forum.

Here is the link :

http://www.nabble.com/Nimble-and-Blogito-to26038767.html

Fabien